# Hashing passwords and AuthComponent

Tags: hash, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to login in my `CakePHP 2.0` application but I always get the login error.
In the official [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout) and the [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) I've read how to hash the passwords, but I still get the login error, here is how I did it:

```
// Users Model
public function beforeSave ($options = array ()) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    return true;
}

// Users Controller
public $components = array ('Acl', 'Session',
    'Auth' => array (
    'authenticate' => array (
        // login e logout sono di default i seguenti controller e views
        // 'loginRedirect' => array ('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        // 'logoutRedirect' => array ('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
        'Form' => array (
            'fields' => array (
            // il valore default 
                'username' => 'email'
            ),
            'scope' => array (
                'User.active' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    'authError' => 'Login error message I get'
));

public function login () {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { // if the request came from post data and not via http (useful for security)
         // the password is hashed in User Model in beforeSave method as read on documentation
         // debug ($this->data);
         if ($this->Auth->login()) {
             $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
             return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>$id, $this->Auth->user('username')));
         } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('Login error message', 'default', array(), 'auth');
         }
    }
}
```

In the view I have this:

```
// the view login.ctp 
echo $this->Form->text('User.email', array('id'=>'email', 'value'=>'your@email.com'));
echo $this->Form->password('User.password', array('id'=>'password', 'value'=>'password'));
```

If I try to debug the data I get this:

```
// in the controller
debug($this->data);
// in the view
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [email] => the@email.com
        [password] => thepass // not hashed
    )
)
```

I can't login because I get always the `Login error message`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Vitto,

(1) Which error message is displayed?

(2) Just for the record, be sure sessionFlash is printed at layout!

```
echo $this->Layout->sessionFlash();
```

(3) How did you set your Auth component? For example, in my AppController I've set this way:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Cookie',
    'Acl',
    /**
     * Default is authorize option is ActionsAuthorize.
     * In this case, system uses AclComponent to check for permissions on an action level.
     * learn more: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authorization
     */
    'Auth'=> array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

(4) Finally, I believe (must be sure) there is no need to manually hash password to perform login. At least, after correct configuration, this code works for me:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            // recirect stuffs
```

Comment: thanks for help 1) I've updated the error in the question. | 2) if I try to print sessionFlash I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function sessionFlash() on a non-object in /public_html/site.com/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp | 3) I'll take a look to this! thanks

Comment: (2) And be sure you've set the helper `Layout` in `$helpers` array at your Controller or AppController. `public $helpers = array(/* others */, 'Layout', /* others */)`;

Comment: maybe you are talking about: `<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>` this works, I using it to get the error

Comment: I said it regarding this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function sessionFlash() on a non-object in /public_html/site.com/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`. If You've try to call `$this->Layout->sessionFlash();` without set `Layout` helper, won't work. Have you already try to check `if($this->Session->check('Auth.User.id')){...}` to know if you has logged successfully at least?

Comment: Are you talking about CakePHP 2.0? `$this->Layout->sessionFlash();` doesn't exist in 2.0 documentation, I think it's changed with `$this->Session->flash('auth');` used to debug the login and session exceptions

Comment: You may try `$this->Session->setFlash($this->authError);` also.